# Finding volume via disk method rotated about the x-axis

Tags: integration, volume

Find the volume generated by revolving the region bounded by the graphs of 
$y=e^{-x}$, $y=0$, $x=0$, $y=1$ about the $x$-axis.

before attempting this problem I noticed the "bounded region" is not fully closed as all the graphs are able to approach positive infinity because $y=e^{-x}$ has the $x$-axis as an asymptote meaning it does not have any roots. However, my book's answer key claims that there is indeed a value for this volume and it is approximately $1.358$.

Answer (score 0):

hint: but volume might still approch a limit. just set the integral under proper limits u shd get the answer

Comment: I don't quite follow, but the way I think about is the solid generated is infinitely large since there is no "bounded region".

Comment: does it result to about 1.358 with the method you mentioned?

Comment: it shd i didnt try. think that 1 + 1/2 + 1/4 +.....  is finite and well defined. that is exactly whts happening here

Comment: So you are saying that the volume approaches a value although the solid is physically infinite?

Comment: indeed. though "solid is infinite" is a very loose concept and you have not defined by what you mean by it but that is exactly the idea in this question.

Comment: @Prandals. Believe it or not, the solid generated is infinitely long, but has a finite (!!) volume. Classical example is Torricelli's horn. Use Calculus to confirm for the e-power. There is a formula for the volume of a rotation about the x-axis.

Answer (score 0):

Note that the bounds correspond to $0<x<\infty.$ Then the volume you seek is \pi $\int_0^\infty e^{-2x}=\pi/2\approx 1.57$. So I would think your book is wrong.